# Configuring of ssh2

Tags: php, centos, centos6, libssh2

I want to delete the cron jobs performed. I'm using the below mentioned code but getting **ssh2** warnings. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**Code**

```
<?php
    $connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

    $cron1      =   ssh2_exec($connection, 'rm -rf index.php*');

    $stream     =   ssh2_exec($connection, 'df -h*');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
?>
```

**PHP info()**
[image]

**Problems**

```
Warning: ssh2_exec(): Unable to request a channel from remote host
Warning: stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource
Warning: ssh2_fetch_stream() expects parameter 1 to be resource
Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Comment: I don't know where I read this, but I think ssh2 does not working on Windows. If that's not your case, try this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921960/ssh2-exec-not-executing-simple-command)

Comment: I have **centOS** not windows.

Comment: I think it'd be easier to figure out what's going on with http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/. eg. http://pastebin.com/RULG7idC The thing with phpseclib is that it provides logging. Once you have the logs if you could edit your post to include them that'd be helpful.