# How to get current directory name from sftp server

Tags: php, libssh2, ssh2-exec

I am connecting to remote sftp server using ssh2 functions. Now I need to get current directory name. In case of ftp server I can use ftp_pwd but I can't find similar function for ssh2

I need php code

Answer (score 3):

Give [`phpseclib`](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) a try for `sftp` connections, you can do easily get the current working dir with its built-in method `pwd`

From the [directory management](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#dir) examples:

```
print $sftp->pwd();
```

Comment: I found this solution 

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'pwd');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$homeDir = stream_get_contents($stream);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only pwd ? Type help for list of available commands

Comment: I tried but it says ssh2_exec(): Unable to request a channel from remote host

Comment: For this one, you can find help on StackOverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921960/ssh2-exec-not-executing-simple-command

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 SFTP server `ssh2_sftp_realpath` returns the same as running `pwd` interactively

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('host.example.com', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'sftptest', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$realpath = ssh2_sftp_realpath($sftp, '.');

# $realpath is now: '/home/sftptest'

$realpath = ssh2_sftp_realpath($sftp, './test');

# $realpath =  /home/sftptest/test

$realpath = ssh2_sftp_realpath($sftp, "../test2");

# $realpath = /home/test2

# note that the directories don't have to exist it just resolves to what it should be based on the current directory
?>
```