# Clone/Push to Git Repository on Local Server

Tags: git

I have just built my first PC (Windows 7) and am setting up a Home Server.  I have installed Apache, PHP, MySQL on the machine and everything is running great.  The server is available to all computers on my network by navigating to IPAddress:Port (using a custom defined port to avoid conflicts) in a browser.

The last step I would like to take is get GIT up and running on the server so that I keep a local copy on my laptop etc and push/pull to the server.  I installed msysgit on the server, created a Media directory in my htdocs folder and created a new git repository there.  When I navigate to the directory in explorer I can see the .git directory.

Now, I have git running on my laptop (MacBook Pro) through the command line but I cannot seem to clone the repository from the server.  All of the commands that I try don't seem to be working (git clone //IPAddress:Port/Media, etc).

I'm sure I'm missing something with access or settings but I can't seem to find anything that is pointing me in the right direction.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any error message or similar?

Comment: In the command line on my Mac, sometimes I'll get a not a git repository if I enter something that doesn't make sense when just trying out some commands.  Usually if I hit a command and address git understands I get a cloning message and then it just times out.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the correct git commands? I tried this command: git clone UName@IP:Port/Media.git and got the following response: Cloning into Media... ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.6 port 22: Operation timed out. I'm not sure that port is available through my firewall.  Is the repository info of a clone command supposed to end in .git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up SSH as a server on the Windows box so it can listen for SSH client requests.  Here is a [link to a Stack Overflow thread on SSH servers for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows).