# SSH connection refused conencting from Unix server to Windows server

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I am trying to execute the below command in putty.

```
ssh username@servername
```

I am getting the below error messsage:

```
ssh: connect to host servername port 22: Connection refused
```

I am trying to connect to a Windows server from a Unix server. Please help me!

Comment: This error means that port `22` is closed or nobody is listening to it. Are you sure you have `SSH` daemon running on windows machine?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The main think is that Windows Server doesn't contain ssh daemon in the box. You could install `telnet server` from the `Windows components` and connect from unix to windows machine by `telnet` command or use 3d-party ssh servers/cygwin.

More available on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows). (*How ironic, both topics are closed as offtopic*)